# DBLP parser java OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, parsing, xml-parsing

I want to parse DBLP dataset into simple output like this

```
Munir Cochinwala: C. Lee - K. C. Lee  
Hongli Deng: Linda Shapiro - Linda G. Shapiro    
William Retert: John Boyland - John Tang Boyland   
Ales Prazák: Josef V. Psutka - Josef Psutka
M. N. S. Swamy: C. Duanmu - C. J. Duanmu
Bonifacio Martín Galán: Maria del Carmen Arellano Pardo - Carmen Arellano
........
```

I've tried their [simple parser](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/faq/How+to+parse+dblp+xml.html), but kinda out of heap space. Then I've included xerceslmp.jar into project library. Also I've increases its memory upto 2G with **-Xmx2G** but I still got Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded. I made this project in Netbeans and had customized its default running config with those param.

*edited
Here is my java

```
dhcPlus-mbp:fresh-run macbook$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on a project involving DBLP recently, and I had the same issue.
What worked for me:

javac Parser.java
java (-mx900M) -DentityExpansionLimit=1000000 Parser dblp.xml > filename.txt

I recommend omitting (-mx900M), it's a piece of optimization for your memory, but only does so correctly if your have java 1.5 (which I don't think). it's just because this people used some stone-age xml parser .

I recommend you try a few different versions of Java. The parser is written in Java 1.6, and that's the version I used.